# Scala named arguments with default (generics type) arguments

Tags: java, scala

In the scala code below, the `NullPointerException` is throwed at the entrance of the 3rd method invocation. I have checked the bytecode. It seems that, in the `f(1, c=2)`, the compiler insert a checkcast on `f$default$2`'s return value which cast `b`'s type to `Nothing`. But in the `f(1)`, the compiler doesn't do such casting. why?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect._
object test {
    def f[T : ClassTag](a:T, b:T=null.asInstanceOf[T], c:Int=2)={ print("*"+classTag[T]+"*");println(a, b, c) }
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        f(1)
        f(1, 2)
        f(1, c=3) //Null pointer!! But why f(1) is right? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to reason about when compiler do or doesn't apply runtime checks, I'll leave to some compiler expert, but `.asinstanceOf` is very likely to send errors  in applying `Nothing` when type parameters are unbounded.

So general rule - try to get rid of `.asInstanceOf` in all possible situations.

For your method one legit definition could be

```
def f[T >: Null : ClassTag](a: T, b: T = null, c: Int = 2) = { ... }
```

Comment: A good general rule. And I summarized a general rule as that never use generics types in default value of a default argument. However, I can't make other more examples to support the statement：）

Answer (score 0):

`null.asInstanceOf` is a bad idea, regardless (never cast nulls!).
Removing it, does fix the NPE, but the ClasTag becomes *Nothing*.

It looks like the runtime is trying to use the second param to extract the ClassTag in this case and fails miserably. Now, why it does this in this case, but not the first case `f(1)`, I have no idea.
Interestingly enough, `f(1, null.asInstanceOf[Int], 3)` works too, so the problem must have something to do with the way default parameters are resolved.

You can also do `f[Int](1, c=3)`. This works.

Better yet, avoid using nulls altogether. This is scala. `null` reference is kinda like `goto` in java: you can use it, but really, really, really should not.

Comment: Thank you very much. You mean I should use the Option's None instead of null in such cases all the way?

Comment: Pretty much. And not just "in such cases" - always. The only reason null even exists in Scala is interoperability with Java. There are no good uses for it otherwise.